# Fuzzy c-mean clustering

Tags: matlab, fuzzy

```
[centers,U,obj_fcn] = fcm(sod,5);
expo = 2.0;                             
max_iter = 100;                         
min_impro = 1e-6; 
figure,
scatter3(sod1(:,1),sod1(:,2),sod1(:,3),'ob')
hold on
scatter3(sod2(:,1),sod2(:,2),sod2(:,3),'oc')
scatter3(sod3(:,1),sod3(:,2),sod3(:,3),'og')
scatter3(sod4(:,1),sod4(:,2),sod4(:,3),'or')
scatter3(sod5(:,1),sod5(:,2),sod5(:,3),'om')
scatter3(centers(1,1),centers(1,2),centers(1,3),'xb','Sizedata',100,'LineWidth',3)
scatter3(centers(2,1),centers(2,2),centers(2,3),'xc','Sizedata',100,'LineWidth',3)
scatter3(centers(3,1),centers(3,2),centers(3,3),'xg','Sizedata',100,'LineWidth',3)
scatter3(centers(4,1),centers(4,2),centers(4,3),'xr','Sizedata',100,'LineWidth',3)
scatter3(centers(5,1),centers(5,2),centers(5,3),'xm','Sizedata',100,'LineWidth',3)
legend('P.1','P.2','P.3','P.4','P.5','P.1 center','P.2 center','P.3 center','P.4 center','P.5 center')
hold off
title 'Fuzzy C Mean';
view(3), axis vis3d, box on, rotate3d on
xlim ([0 10])
ylim ([0 10])
zlim ([0 10])
xlabel('Severity')
ylabel('Occurrence')
zlabel('Detect')
```

The centroids of the fuzzy c-mean clustering are different once I run the code everytime.Is there any wrong ?

[image]

Sod1 to sod5 is the part of the data of sod, I extract them into parts

Answer (score 0):

From the [`fcm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/fcm.html#buw31w5-6) documentation:

> `fcm` performs the following steps during clustering:
>          1   Randomly initialize the cluster membership values, μ<sub>ij</sub>.

Because the optimization problem is initialized randomly, and it likely gets stuck in a local minimum, it will find a different result each time.

One way to use k-means and fuzzy c-means (these are very similar) is to run the clustering multiple times and see if any set of centers is found more often than the others. That is probably the most stable of the local minima.

If you need a deterministic approach, roll your own version of the function and give it a deterministic initialization. The built-in method doesn’t seem to have this option. Though maybe you can set the seed if the random number generator to a fixed vale before calling the function? A simple

```
rng(0);
[centers,U,obj_fcn] = fcm(sod,5);
```

would accomplish this. [See the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html).